# APEX 20.1 - Styling Column Group Heading of Interactive Grid

Tags: css, grid, styles, interactive, oracle-apex-20.1

Does anyone have an example showing how column headings can be styled in an Interactive Grid?

I would like the column headings in each of the 4 different Column Groups to have a different background color to make the groups more distinguishable:
[image]

[image]

It doesn't look like there is a way to easily assign a style to the Column Group via the developer interface.  So, I've tried to use the TH ID:

```
#R141502556723241100_ig_grid_vc_cur {
    background-color: #242d45;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

but instead of changing the background-color for the Term/Element TH, it changes the background-color for whatever element is clicked on.

- - 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a static ID to your IG.

- Static ID: my-static-id

Then you can use the following css snippet:

```css
/*

where the value between the quotation marks ("") is the index of the column heading

*/
#my-static-id  th[data-idx="0"] { 
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

#my-static-id  th[data-idx="1"] {
  background-color: green;
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, i am using column groups as well. What if i just want to color the column groups and not column headers?